# How can I use XSLT to assemble an XML Hierarchy

Tags: xslt

Given this XML

> ```
> <Xml>
>     <Thing id="1"  >
>         <Foo id="11" parentId="12"/>
>         <Foo id="12"/>
>     </Thing>
>     <Thing id="2" parentId="1" />
>     <Thing id="3" parentId="2" />
>     <Thing id="4">
>         <Foo id="11" parentId="15"/>
>         <Foo id="12" parentId="14"/>
>         <Foo id="13" parentId="11"/>
>         <Foo id="14" parentId="15"/>
>         <Foo id="15"/>      
>     </Thing>
> </Xml>
> ```

I want to grab every collection of siblings, and assemble them into their own hierarchy.

Every "Thing" node with a parentId value, should nest under the corresponding Thing node.
Every "Foo" node with a parentId value, should nest under the corresponding Foo node -- but only within its siblings.  The example has two sets of Foo siblings.

I'm trying to create this:

> ```
> <Xml>
>     <Thing id="1" >
>         <Foo id="12">
>             <Foo id="11" parentId="12"/>
>         </Foo>        
>         <Thing id="2" parentId="1" >
>             <Thing id="3" parentId="2" />
>         </Thing>
>     </Thing>            
>     <Thing id="4" >
>         <Foo id="14" parentId="12">
>             <Foo id="12" parentId="14"/>
>         </Foo>
>         <Foo id="15">
>             <Foo id="11" parentId="15">
>                 <Foo id="13" parentId="11"/>
>             </Foo>
>         </Foo>
>     </Thing>
> </Xml>
> ```

This example comes close:
[How can I use XSLT 1.0 to add structure to a non-heirarchal XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981835/how-can-i-use-xslt-1-0-to-add-structure-to-a-non-heirarchal-xml-file)

I've used the identity template to retain all nodes and attributes.  Then I want an overriding template to match on all nodes that have a sibling (following or preceding) such that the sibling's @parentId value equals my @id value.  The closest I could come was hard coding an id/parentId value to match on.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
>
>     <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
>
>     <!-- override identity rule with template to match on
>         a node who has siblings, where sibling/@parentId == ./@id
>     -->
>     <xsl:template match="node()[@id='1' and (preceding-sibling::*[@parentId = 1] or following-sibling::*[@parentId = 1])]">
>        <captured>
>         <xsl:copy>
>             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
>         </xsl:copy>
>        </captured>
>     </xsl:template>  
>
>
>     <!-- identity rule -->
>     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
>         <xsl:copy>
>             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
>         </xsl:copy>
>     </xsl:template>
>
>
> </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```

I can't see how to grab the current nodes @id value to use in the predicate of the Xpath matching siblings based on parentId value.

And then I want to nest the current nodes siblings underneath it, where the siblings @ParentId equals my @id.

Comment: There is a subtle error in the provided XML document -- a pair of unreachable `Foo` elements that form a closed circuit and cannot be a part of an hierarchy. Please, correct. Regardless of this I +1 this question, because it is interesting.

Comment: Error corrected.  Thanks.  Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First of all do notice an error in the provided XML document**:

```
    <Foo id="12" parentId="14"/>
    <Foo id="13" parentId="11"/>
    <Foo id="14" parentId="12"/>
```

There is a circular relation between `Foo` with `id` 12 and `Foo` with `14`. This makes a cycle and isn't "hierarchy". Also, these two `Foo` elements are *unreachable* from the top of the hierarchy! **Please, correct**.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElemById" match="*"
   use="concat(generate-id(..), '+', @id)"/>
 <xsl:key match="*" name="kDescendants"
  use="concat(generate-id(key('kElemById', 
                              concat(generate-id(..), '+',@parentId))),
             '+', @parentId)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Xml>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(@parentId)]"/>
  </Xml>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(@parentId)]"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "key('kDescendants', concat(generate-id(), '+',  @id))"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Xml>
    <Thing id="1"  >
        <Foo id="11" parentId="12"/>
        <Foo id="12"/>
    </Thing>
    <Thing id="2" parentId="1" />
    <Thing id="3" parentId="2" />
    <Thing id="4">
        <Foo id="11" parentId="15"/>
        <Foo id="12" parentId="14"/>
        <Foo id="13" parentId="11"/>
        <Foo id="14" parentId="12"/>
        <Foo id="15"/>
    </Thing>
</Xml>
```

**produces correct result, excluding any unreachable elements**:

```
<Xml>
   <Thing id="1">
      <Foo id="12">
         <Foo id="11" parentId="12"/>
      </Foo>
      <Thing id="2" parentId="1">
         <Thing id="3" parentId="2"/>
      </Thing>
   </Thing>
   <Thing id="4">
      <Foo id="15">
         <Foo id="11" parentId="15">
            <Foo id="13" parentId="11"/>
         </Foo>
      </Foo>
   </Thing>
</Xml>
```