# How can I use XSLT to combine two XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

i try code from [How can I use XSLT to assemble an XML Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762376/how-can-i-use-xslt-to-assemble-an-xml-hierarchy)

a.xml:

```
    <Xml>
        <Classes>
            <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="11"/>
            <Class Name="PHYSICS101" ClassId="13"/>
            <Class Name="CALCULUS101" ClassId="17"/>
            <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="19"/>
        </Classes>
    </Xml>
```

b.xml :

```
<Xml>
    <Students>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="11"/>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="19"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="11"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="13"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="13"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="19"/>
    </Students>
</Xml>
```

Stylesheet (merge.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Class">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <!-- Apply <Student> elements from b.xml -->
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="document('b.xml')/Xml/Students/Student
          [@ClassId = current()/@ClassId]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Student">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@Name"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

hope output :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Xml>
  <Classes>
    <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="11">
      <Student Name="Bob Johnson"/>
      <Student Name="Joe Jackson"/>
    </Class>
    <Class Name="PHYSICS101" ClassId="13">
      <Student Name="Joe Jackson"/>
      <Student Name="Rick Robertson"/>
    </Class>
    <Class Name="CALCULUS101" ClassId="17">
      <Student Name="Bob Johnson"/>
      <Student Name="Joe Jackson"/>
      <Student Name="Rick Robertson"/>
    </Class>
    <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="19">
      <Student Name="Bob Johnson"/>
      <Student Name="Rick Robertson"/>
    </Class>
  </Classes>
</Xml>
```

but when i launching with a.xml, i get the result is BLANK..
nothing showing anything in my browser mozilla..
(note : in header a.xml i write this code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge.xsl"?>
```

somebody can me please ??
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine. Press `F12` in order to view the result. For more information Please refer why browser (Firefox/Chrome) is showing blank result.

Attached screenshot (Developer tool)

[image]

[Why XSLT is not working in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941662/xslt-not-working-in-web-browser)

Comment: still not working @nawazlj

and i have look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941662/xslt-not-working-in-web-browser , but still not working..

Comment: @Rijal can you add your screenshot what it is coming after pressing `F12`.

Comment: i just know after press f12, showing the result:
@nawazlj thanks buudy it's working :)

Comment: @Rijal if it's correct answer then please accept answer

Comment: can you help me please again..
i want my result use stylesheet like :
<div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
  Nim Mahasiswa : <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="nim_mahasiswa"/></span>
    </div>

example, how to my result using table..
best regards..
Rijal

Comment: after look your screenshot, i already know look in tab class..
and it's working.. 
i got what i want, thanks buddy (y) @nawazlj